# validating a math equation with rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the sign up form on my site to have a field that takes the sum of a math equation and use rails validation to validate it. Whats the best way to do it?

i.e

What is 6 + 9 ?  [ 8  ]

Error Message : You have entered the wrong number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `validate` method in your model class. Remember that the model object you create for the `new` action is a different instance than the one created for the `create` action, so you'll need to save the random seed or the math expression somewhere in your form so that you can recreate it during validation.

Then, something along the lines of:

```
def validate
  unless math_equation_answered?
    errors.add("math_answer", "is incorrect")
  end
end
```

The implementation of `math_equation_answered?` is up to you, and `math_answer` should be changed to whatever model field you use for the user's answer.